# Where to group-catch thread messages WINAPI/MFC

Tags: winapi, mfc

Does anyone know where is the best place to forward thread messages to child controls?

Basically, app has to catch registered thread messages in range msg_frst...msg_last and forward them to active frame/view.

There are 3 overload points in MFC, or so it seems:
DefWndProc
OnWndMessage
PreTranslateMessage

Which is the correct one to override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A message posted with PostThreadMessage() has a NULL window handle.  So forget about any of the window methods, DispatchMessage() isn't going to deliver them.  All you got is CWinThread::PreTranslateMessage().

But there's a big hazard here, this isn't going to be called anymore when any code in that thread start pumping its own message loop.  Your messages now fall in the bit bucket because other code is now calling Peek/GetMessage().  That's a lot more likely then you think, MessageBox() is enough.  Or the COM modal loop.  Etcetera.

You can only safely use PostThreadMessage() to send messages to a thread that does *not* create any windows of its own.  The workaround is simple enough, provide the thread with a window handle so it can call PostMessage() instead.  That could be a hidden window, dedicated to handling these messages for example.

Comment: Wow, didn't think of it :( Now I'm completely stuck with the message passing towards child windows...

Comment: Wow.  At the enormous amount of pain I saved you from with this answer.  Two weeks?  Really?